# Is it possible to assign address value directly to a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm learning C++ from [www.learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com). The tutorials are good and I could ask the author myself by commenting but it takes some time to get a reply. So, here is something I'm confused in [lesson 23.7](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/random-file-io/) near the end of the lesson.

> **A warning about writing pointers to disk**

> While streaming variables to a file is quite easy, things become more complicated when you’re dealing with pointers. Remember that a pointer simply holds the address of the variable it is pointing to. Although it is possible to read and write addresses to disk, it is extremely dangerous to do so. This is because a variable’s address may differ from execution to execution. Consequently, although a variable may have lived at address 0x0012FF7C when you wrote that address to disk, it may not live there any more when you read that address back in!

> For example, let’s say you had an integer named nValue that lived at address 0x0012FF7C. You assigned nValue the value 5. You also declared a pointer named *pnValue that points to nValue. pnValue holds nValue’s address of 0x0012FF7C. You want to save these for later, so you write the value 5 and the address 0x0012FF7C to disk.

> A few weeks later, you run the program again and read these values back from disk. You read the value 5 into another variable named nValue, which lives at 0x0012FF78. You read the address 0x0012FF7C into a new pointer named *pnValue. Because pnValue now points to 0x0012FF7C when the nValue lives at 0x0012FF78, pnValue is no longer pointing to nValue, and trying to access pnValue will lead you into trouble.

It's written as if we could store an address like `0x0012ff78` and retrieve it directly back to a pointer. Hence the question, since I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you can assign an address value directly to a pointer.  `int* p = (int*)0x0012ff78;`  The only time I've had a need to do that was working with memory mapped I/O registers.

Comment: All that gets written to a file is bytes. A pointers value consists of bytes, so there's no problem writing those bytes to a file (or reading the same bytes back from the file). Except that as your tutorial states it's meaningless to do so, and will likely crash your program.

Comment: The quote probably just refers to writing and reading the (binary) object representation of the pointer value to memory, not getting a numeric value representing the address and then writing/reading that (which also works via `reinterpret_cast` to/from `uintptr_t` on most implementations). In any case, the quote explains why neither of these should be done.

Comment: Yes, you can store an address to a file ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/vKcrPx994)) - but if you store it and then close the program and restart the program and try to use the pointer stored to file, you will have troubles as the article mentions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, and in C++ it looks something like:

```
auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<ptr_type>(0x0012FF7C);
```

Where `ptr_type` is a valid pointer type, like `int*` for example.

---

To add a bit more clarity to the problem outlined in the lesson:

Memory addresses are constantly being reclaimed and reused as required by the different programs running on a system.

When your program starts running, the OS keeps track of which memory addresses your program is allowed to access. When your program ends, those memory address are reclaimed by the OS for use by another process which might need it.

If you restart your program and attempt to modify or access (de-reference) the information stored at a particular address, which your program did not explicitly request for, the OS will/*should* detect this and may decide to end the program.

Comment: However, anything you may or may not be allowed to do with the resulting pointer is completely implementation-defined. Trying to access a random address like this will almost surely just crash your program.

Comment: @user17732522 oh most assuredly :)

Comment: Since in this example the address is hard coded, I'd add a `const` somewhere, just as reminder ;-)

Comment: @MatG you mean to make the value pointed at a const? So something like `const ptr_type`?

Comment: The only case this makes sense at all is accessing hardware directly in a kernel and then you would also add `volatile`. And always remember this is totally implementation defined.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the OS will load the program at the same address every time.

Comment: @smac89 No no I meant const pointer to whatever